# how to add condition when i use unique function in validation in laravel framwork

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two databases; the first database contains a table called product which contains id, status, deleted.

The second database contains a table called product which contains id, id_product, name, price.

I use validation rule uniq as below:

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'name'  =>'required|max:25|min:1|unique:mysql2.products,name|alpha',
            'price' =>'required'
            ]);
```

and it works well, but if I want to make condition with unique function like below:

```
"select * from `product` where `name`=? AND `status`=? and `deleted `=?",array($name,1,1)
```

how can I make a unique function to accept condition like

```
`status`=? AND `deleted`=?
```

Comment: Could you explain the condition part? I mean, in plain english :)

Comment: Ii mean in laravel validation when i use uique it mean check data in all recodd on table but that i want is check data on all table that status = 1 and deleted = 1 thts kinda of filltering data  status and deleted is filltering coulmn in data base that i created

Answer (score 0):

You could make a [Custom Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules):

```
php artisan make:rule UniqueActive
```

then in your newly created class:

**app/Rules/UniqueActive.php**

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Uppercase implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return ! Product
                   ::where('name', '=', $value)
                   ::where('status', 1)
                   ::where('deleted', 1)
                   ::exists();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute is not unique.';
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
use App\Rules\UniqueActive;

//

$this->validate($request,[
            'name'  => ['required', 'max:25', 'min:1', 'alpha', new UniqueActive],
            'price' => 'required',                          //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ]);
```